# CakePHP Blog Tutorial Editing Posts- How is the submitted data available to the edit action?

Tags: cakephp-2.3

When the 'Edit' button is clicked on the index view, the data is first submitted to the PostsController Edit action. Since the 'set' function is not called within that action, how is the edit.ctp view rendered and the edited data posted back to the Edit action?

Comment: use a debugger / do tracing.

Answer (score 0):

You should paste in the code from your controller, so people can see exactly what you're talking about.

Assuming you've got a pretty standard edit method, it should contain a line something like this:

`$this->request->data = $this->Post->read(null, $id)`

So, the `$this->request->data` is set. Cake makes sure the whole `$this->request` is available in the view. In the View superclass, there's an array called `$_passedVars`, which includes, among other things, `request`. In the `__construct` of the view, it copies every variable named in `$_passedVars` from the controller, over to the view.

If you want to see the detail, check out `/lib/Cake/View/View.php`, in particular, the `$_passedVars` variable, and the first several lines of the `__construct` method:

```
/**
 * List of variables to collect from the associated controller.
 *
 * @var array
 */
    protected $_passedVars = array(
        'viewVars', 'autoLayout', 'ext', 'helpers', 'view', 'layout', 'name', 'theme',
        'layoutPath', 'viewPath', 'request', 'plugin', 'passedArgs', 'cacheAction'
    );
```

and

```
/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param Controller $controller A controller object to pull View::_passedVars from.
 */
    public function __construct(Controller $controller = null) {
        if (is_object($controller)) {
            $count = count($this->_passedVars);
            for ($j = 0; $j < $count; $j++) {
                $var = $this->_passedVars[$j];
                $this->{$var} = $controller->{$var};
            }
            $this->_eventManager = $controller->getEventManager();
        }
        if (empty($this->request) && !($this->request = Router::getRequest(true))) {
            $this->request = new CakeRequest(null, false);
            $this->request->base = '';
            $this->request->here = $this->request->webroot = '/';
        }
        if (is_object($controller) && isset($controller->response)) {
            $this->response = $controller->response;
        } else {
            $this->response = new CakeResponse();
        }
        $this->Helpers = new HelperCollection($this);
        $this->Blocks = new ViewBlock();
        $this->loadHelpers();
        parent::__construct();
    }
```